# Why is CSS 'padding' creating a margin in my element?

Tags: css, margin, padding

I have a 'ul' with a width of 100%, but when I put 'padding' in it, a right margin appears. Why is it happening? The code is below.

```css
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(90, 32, 102);
  line-height: 3.125em;
  position: relative;
  right: 38px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: That's because it's `position:relative;` and `right:38px;`.

Comment: It's not `margin`, it's the `right: 38px` pushing it to the left 38px. This is why there's no left margin either - technically, the left side of your nav is just being pushed off the screen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `position: relative` and `right: 38px` is not idiomatic here. It is saying to move the right edge of the ul elements to the left of where they would normally be by `38px`, creating a right margin. The best first step would likely be to remove these two properties.

It seems like you want a centered list without bullets, which would be the result. The ul indent is set with `padding`, which is already set to 0 on the left.

At first, I misread the question thinking that the li elements were breaking the style by being too wide. The advice given was accepted, so I assume it was helpful if not the answer.

Padding extends beyond the width of an element by default, so your ul blocks are actually `100% + 1em` *tall*.

Using the `box-sizing` property of css to apply `box-sizing: border-box;` would create the expected behavior.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

> **border-box**
>   The width and height properties include the content, padding, and
>   border, but do not include the margin. Note that padding and border
>   will be inside of the box. For example, .box {width: 350px; border:
>   10px solid black;} renders a box that is 350px wide. The content box
>   can't be negative and is floored to 0, making it impossible to use
>   border-box to make the element disappear.

Comment: he added padding-top/bottom

Comment: Although, using `*{ box-sizing:border-box; }` is a good practice, it's not the problem here. By the way default is already `box-sizing:content-box;`. This answer may confuse OP.

Comment: Please explain how this is the correct answer. There is no way setting something that is already set will change anything.

Comment: @PHPglue worth to note that it acually contains wrong information because `padding:1em 0` will not make the element `100% + 1em` wider ...

Comment: @HienNguyen Thanks for the encouraging comment. I will switch it back with a correct answer prepended.

Answer (score -2):

It's because the ul has a default `padding-left` (`40px`) that you made equal to 0 and you can see the `38px` on the right due to `position:relative;right:38px`.

Note that the `width:100%` is also a culprit because with the default padding added to it you will have overflow so pushing the element to left (using `right:38px`) isn't enough to see an empty space:

```css
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(90, 32, 102);
  line-height: 3.125em;
  position: relative;
  right: 38px;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
width 100% + default padding creating an overflow
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
width is now auto, so no more overflow and we see the 38px
<nav>
  <ul style="width:auto">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
padding is now 0, so no more overflow and we see the 38px
<nav>
  <ul style="padding:1em 0">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Using `position: relative` to remove the left spacing on list items is not idiomatic css. It appears to work correctly, but does not reserve the correct space in the document flow.

Comment: @trognanders you should told this to the OP, I am not using position:relative to remove the space, I am explaining the behavior of his code